# Transaction Deadlocked on SQL - Basic Update Queries Only

Tags: sql-server

As traffic to our website has been increasing, we are starting to get deadlock errors.  I have spent countless hours trying to figure out why since it's only happening on UPDATE queries and they are very simple - always updating a single row in the same table (different rows by each query).

We grabbed the deadlock information from the Extended Events file under Management in SQL Server Management Studio.

Here is a sample:

```
EXEC upd_root_step1 '44F57855-74B6-4746-B615-69BCCA721BDA', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'
```

That query performs the following update:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE Roots SET Q1 = @Q1, Q2 = @Q2, Q3 = @Q3, Q4 = @Q4, Q5 = @Q5, Q6 = @Q6, Q7 = @Q7, Q8 = @Q8, Q9 = @Q9 WHERE RootGUID = @RootGUID
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

The second query as part of the deadlock error is:

```
EXEC upd_root_card '2f2cc09b-9240-43c5-83c5-d34be93c6533',1
```

This relates to:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE Roots SET RootOnFile = @Status WHERE RootGUID = @RootGUID
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Nothing else happens in the Stored Proc calls. that's it.  VERY basic.

The way I understand it, the queries are locking the table at the same time, but why??  The queries are NOT accessing or updating the same rows.  There is no index in the RootGUID field, but it's a `uniqueindentfier` field, I did not think you needed them on UID field types.  I did wrap the queries with BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION, but it did not change anything.

I have read this about deadlocks, not sure it applies to me fully since I am not getting deadlock with a SELECT. (READ_COMMITTED)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191242(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Deadlock Graph from another table with a deadlock I traced.

[image]

Any help would be MUCH appreciated, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is your table structure, and what indexes, constraints, FK's, dependencies, etc?  All things to check out that may be the issue.  Do you have an execution plan you can share?

Comment: @Brad - none of the queries update anything that's indexed or FK.  The WHERE is just GUID.  This is not the same for all my tables, but I think if I fix the issues with this, i will know the issues on other queries this is happening with.   As for execution plan, it told me i should have an index on the GUID, so I added.  I want to see if that helps.  It's very basic - Clustered Index Update, Parallelism, Clustered Index Scan (99.9% on this one).

Comment: In the snippets you provided the transaction blocks are useless. There is only one statement contain within the transaction statement, and the commit is implicit if you get rid of begin/commit transaction. I can't really see the point of using stored procedures for something that basic. Possibly you could merge all your statements into one single SP and then a transaction would make sense for the purpose of data integrity. It is also possible that the error comes from another process trying to update the Roots table.

Comment: We need to see the deadlock graph in order to assist.

Comment: @Anonymous  Yes, i know about the the blocks.  I had spent so much time troubleshooting this, I was trying anything to help.  Dale, I posted the graph above from another deadlock error we got.  I got the SP's from Extended Events - they were the two calls in there that caused the deadlock.  Yes, they are very basic queries, but they are reused in multiple places so just easier to make changes in the SP vs 10 different pages in code....  thanks for the help everyone, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We went from 50-100 of these errors/day to none overnight after I added the index on the one table for RootGUID. It seems the issue was the index.

Can someone please explain why that is so I understand moving forward? Was the query just taking too long since no index even though a single record updated?

Thank you.